# page background image transition on scroll via css3/javascript

Tags: css, scroll, transition

I am looking for some solution for page's background image (animation) transition on scroll when move to next or previous div via scrolling or link button.
Here is the example site http://zurb.com/manifesto background with objects move/animate along scroll. If anyone could help with this technique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is a **parallax scrolling** plugin. Here are some links with a couple of options:

- http://www.impressivewebs.com/parallax-scrolling-scripts-plugins/
- http://smashinghub.com/7-jquery-parallax-and-scrolling-effect-plugins.htm
- http://idesignow.com/jquery/9-jquery-parallax-scrolling-plugins-tutorials.html#.UWtI4LWZ-vs

And here are a couple of tutorials:

- http://richardshepherd.com/smashing/parallax/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique
- http://pepsized.com/merry-scrolling-with-skrollr-js/

Once you know what it is called you will be able to find more examples and tutorials to help you out.

Comment: No problem. I don't have any major experience with any of them, but am currently using skrollr.js for a project. Seems to be very good example of this type of plugin.